# Solving the PDE: $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}-\phi f$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I would like find a solution $\{\phi(x,t);t\in\mathbb{R}^+,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of the following PDE:

$$
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}-\phi f(x) ,
$$
with boundary conditions
$$
\phi(0,x)=1,\text{ and }\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(0,x)=f(x).
$$
The function $f$ will ideally be as general as possible. If such generality is unhelpful, then I am willing to consider any particular choice of $f$ satisfying:

1. $f(x)=f(-x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
2. $f>0$, and
3. $f(x)<f(y)$ for any $|x|>|y|$.

For example, $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ or $f(x)=1/(e^x+e^{-x})$.

This seemingly simple looking problem is completely baffling me. Does anyone have any suggestion for how to proceed? Do we even have existence and uniqueness?

Comment: Getting an analytical solution for some arbitrary $f(\phi)$ is a *very* hard problem. You'll be quite famous if you ever figure out how to do that. Occasionally, you can transform your PDE to be linear again depending on what $f(\phi)$ is. Do you have a specific $f$ that you're interesting in?

Comment: The function $f$ is a function of $x$,  not $\phi$.  Hopefully this is clearer now that I have slightly edited the question.

Comment: As a parabolic equation, it can have some similarity solution...

Comment: Perhaps I did not get that well, but I think you only provided the initial conditions for your problem...

Comment: This is quite similar in form to the linear Schrodinger equation... for the case where $f$ is a positive constant function (and thus satisfying your 3 conditions), this can be easily solved via substitution $\psi = \exp(ft)\phi$.

Comment: Thanks  Alexander,  that works nicely. Ideally $f$ will not be constant however.  I have edited the condition 3 now.

Comment: You're not going to find an explicit solution for any non-trivial set of functions $f$.

Comment: The equation is first order in $t$. You cannot specify a condition on $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}$ at $t=0$.